# Reconstruct Tracks

Tags: qgis, points-to-line, tracking, movement-data

I got a CSV file with a bunch of waypoints from different users tracking their routes. Each waypoint has information about time, UserId and RouteId. These points are already implemented in QGIS 3.14.16, however I want to connect the waypoints to get tracks.

Since each route was taken by another individual, they end at some point and will not connect to another track. I already tried "Points-to-line" which is not working.

ArcGIS offers "Reconstruct Tracks" which is what I am looking for in QGIS, since it is not possible for me to use ArcGIS due to several reasons. And since I am not very familiar with python I am looking for a plugin or any other tool within QGIS.

Comment: Have you checked out this qGIS plugin? https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/reconstruct_line/

Comment: Please elaborate on Points-to-Line "not working". Have you tried Points-to-Path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Points to Path`, set `Order field` to the field with your time information (or any other order field, in my case simply the `id`) and set the `RouteID` field as `Group field` to get a separate line for each single value of this field.

*Red line created from the blue points with `Points to Path`. As the points have three different values for `track_id`, three different lines are created:*
[image]